# Setting property of objective-C class from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, setter

I have a class `MyClass` subclassed from `NSObject`. It is written in Objective-C. It has a property with custom getter and setter:

```
    @interface MyClass : NSObject

        @property (getter = getIsBypassEnabled, setter = setIsBypassEnabled:) BOOL isBypassEnabled;

    @end
```

And both of these functions are defined in implementation:

```
    @implementation MyClass

    // Initializer and other stuff
    // ...

    -   (void) setIsBypassEnabled: (BOOL) newValue
    {
        _value = newValue;
    }

    -   (BOOL) getIsBypassEnabled
    {
        return _value;
    }

   @end
```

But when I try to set the property from Swift like:

```
let objcClass = MyClass()
objcClass.isBypassEnabled = true
```

I get an error `'isBypassEnabled' has been renamed to 'getIsBypassEnabled'`. But I need to set the value, not get it!

Trying

```
objcClass.setIsBypassEnabled(true)
```

gives me an error that my class has no such member.

Declaring

```
-   (BOOL) getIsBypassEnabled;
-   (void) setIsBypassEnabled: (BOOL) newValue;
```

explicitly in .h file does not help either.

How do I resolve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (getter = getIsBypassEnabled, setter = setIsBypassEnabled:) BOOL isBypassEnabled;
@end
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
open class MyClass : NSObject {
    open var getIsBypassEnabled: Bool
}
```

so you can set the property actually with

```
let objcClass = MyClass()
objcClass.getIsBypassEnabled = true
```

I don't know if this mapping is intended or not, you might want to
file a bug report.

You can also override the Swift mapping with

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (getter = getIsBypassEnabled, setter = setIsBypassEnabled:) BOOL isBypassEnabled
   NS_SWIFT_NAME(isBypassEnabled);
@end
```

and then

```
let objcClass = MyClass()
objcClass.isBypassEnabled = true
```

works as intended.

Comment: The actual situation makes no sense at all, because it mismatches property and getter, which only has the same name on default. No problem, will be repaired, one has to change the code with the next release of Swift again …